# Woocommerce Shipping Method radio buttons not updating

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce

I'm currently working on a site using a custom theme and woocommerce (no other plugins active) and am having trouble with the cart/checkout page. I'm using the same page for both the cart and the checkout which I know can work with woocommerce.

The problem I'm having is that the radio buttons controlling shipping methods don't update the cart totals. By default, it selects "flat rate" at £3.25 but when I select "free shipping" or "local pickup" the totals stay the same. However, when I place the order, the shipping method is correct so I think it must be a problem with the way AJAX is updating (or in this case not) updating the cart totals.

When looking at the HTML of the page while selecting the shipping method the radio button tag checked="checked" doesn't appear on the radio button I'm selecting only the default one.

I've also located the update_shipping function in abstract-wc-order.php and can't see anything wrong with the code so am at a loss why it isn't updating.

Should probably mention we're using a custom theme which we've built from scratch. When using woocommerce is there any specific code which needs to be included in the head (which we might not have as we wrote it ourselves) for certain javascript/AJAX code to work properly on the site?

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman I'm using Chrome Developer Tools if that's what you mean by console and no I'm not getting any errors there, also just realised that the shop page displaying all products has the same problem when choosing how to sort the products.

Comment: Is it making any Ajax calls while clicking on radio button.? Share your site link

Comment: @MujeebuRahman We're currently building the site offline on a wamp server so unfortunately (and very unhelpfully) I won't be able to share a link to the site. How would I be able to tell if it was making any AJAX calls?

Comment: Does the same error happen when separating cart & checkout pages?

Comment: Yes that was one of the first things that I tried. I think it must be some sort of deeper problem as I said the dropdown for sorting products doesn't update either.

Comment: Solved. In the end it turned out for whatever reason wp_footer(); was missing from our footer. What an anticlimax.